# Add individual directional arrows on d3 network graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to add individual arrows (one for the path from node A to B, and the other for B to A) to a d3 graph that I have made (see the Plunker version [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vo5Qt7WP0V6Zdp4h7Z0L?p=info)), instead of adding a single arrow with two arrows at each end.

I have tried to modify my tick function as per [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5141278), but this doesn't seem to work (the arrows from A to B, then from B to A are not separated):

```
var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
.data(force.links())
.enter().append("svg:path")
.attr("class", "link")
.attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

function tick() {
path.attr("d", function(d) {
var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
    dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
    dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
return "M" + 
    d.source.x + "," + 
    d.source.y + "A" + 
    dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + 
    d.target.x + "," + 
    d.target.y;
});
```

Does anyone have an idea as to how I can do this?

Best,

Ben

Comment: The link you have sent has the solution. you need to draw curved arrows exactly similar to your link

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought I had done exactly that? Best, Ben

Comment: It is not in your plunker. You are using line there.